# Finding equivalent resistance - does order matter?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, capacitance

Conceptual question: When you have a super complicated circuit, does it matter which node you start at when finding equivalent resistance? How about capacitance?

Comment: For hand calculation via nodal analysis all the selected nodes must be considered, so it makes no difference in which order they're done. What exactly does *how about capacitance?* mean?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to answer this question:

1. If the circuit is really complicated, you will be using a linear algebra or matrix solution method to solve it, not combining elements in any particular order.
2. If changing the order of operations in your method of finding the equivalent resistance creates different results, then one or the other of your methods (or both) is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. Where ever you start is where you have to end in your loop. It's just tradition to start at circuit ground as an origin. And without any other context or assumptions, anyone else you share your findings with are going to assume you are starting or referencing ground.

The sum of voltage sources around a loop always equal the voltages dropped throughout the loop.

And the sum currents into a node always equal the currents leaving a node (otherwise, a charge would accumulate at the node).